# I am getting a error while creating a table in pop SQL MySQL database

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, popsql

Cannot add foreign key constraint

Code :

```
create table works_with (
    emp_id int,
    client_id int,
    total_sales int,
    primary key(emp_id,client_id),
    foreign key(emp_id) references employee(emp_id) on delete cascade,
    foreign key(client_id) references client(client_id) on delete cascade
);
```

Comment: Show DDL for ref. tables and complete error message text.

Comment: Please share the table definition for `employee` and `client` tables. I have created `works_with` table with the given definition, [it is working](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=9dbab291d1a116f8e839561ebd11223b). So required `employee` and `client` table details